# cual es la mejor forma de hacer una transaccion en c# con sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estoy ingresando 5.500.000 registros en una tabla y me resulta muy lento.

Por eso envio una lista de querys para insertar los datos.

De esa forma solo abro y cierro una vez la tabla.

Por un problema de memoria envio 500.000 registros cada vez.

awDatosArchivo contiene: el path del archivo sqlite, el nombre del archivo y el nombre de la tabla

las Query son similares a esta:

```
    INSERT INTO personas (n02NroPersona, n02NroCedula, a02Nombres, a02Apellidos) values ('         1', '       10.7', 'JOSÉ', 'CATEURA BALPARDA')       



    public static bool ejecutarQuery(List<string> awLQuery, AControlArchivo awDatosArchivo)
    {
        bool lwReturn = true;
        string awQuery = "";
        using (SQLiteConnection cn = ConnectToSqlite(awDatosArchivo))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var tra = cn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var myQuery in awLQuery)
                    {
                        awQuery = myQuery;
                        using (var cd = new SQLiteCommand(myQuery, cn, tra))
                        {
                            cd.ExecuteNonQuery();                                
                        }
                    }
                    tra.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tra.Rollback();
                    muestroError(ex);
                    lwReturn = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return lwReturn;
    }

    public static SQLiteConnection ConnectToSqlite(AControlArchivo awDatosArchivo)
    {
        SQLiteConnection connSqlite = null;
        if (awDatosArchivo.awPath.Substring(0, 2) == @"\\")
        {
            awDatosArchivo.awPath = "//" + awDatosArchivo.awPath.Substring(2);
        }
        if (datosPublicos.lwForeignKeyActiva)
        {
            connSqlite = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + awDatosArchivo.awPath + "\\" + awDatosArchivo.awArchivo + ".sqlite; foreign keys=true; Version=3; New=True; Compress=True; Connect Timeout=300");
        }
        else
        {
            connSqlite = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + awDatosArchivo.awPath + "\\" + awDatosArchivo.awArchivo + ".sqlite; foreign keys=false; Version=3; New=True; Compress=True; Connect Timeout=300");
        }
        return connSqlite;
    }
```

Comment: Tienes `SQLiteStatement`?

Comment: es winform, no tengo SQLiteStatement, voy a analizar esa opcion, luego te comento

Comment: Sqlite tiene metodos asincronicos y tambien tiene metodos para agregar un rango de datos para que no debas usar un foreach e insertar uno a uno los registros. El addRange te va a acelerar drasticamente el ingreso de datos. En mi experiencia ingresando 150 mil registros, demoro 1 o 2 seg

Comment: @RamiroBarone yo en el List<string> tengo querys (ahora agregue en mi pregunta un ejemplo) , podrias indicarme un ejemplo de como utilizar addRange ? (he buscado y lo que encontre es como adicionar string a un List, pero no relacionado con sqlite)

Comment: @Bicho todo lo que encontre sobre SQLiteStatement esta relacionado con android, puedo utilizarlo en WinForm ?

Comment: Te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852068/sqlite-insert-very-slow

Comment: Que libreria usas?

Comment: @RamiroBarone System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.112.2

Comment: Perdon la demora. Podrias cambiar de libreria para trabajar y usar sqlite-net-pcl? la misma tiene los metodos para insercion masiva. Sino me parece que deberias trabajar con multi hilo iterando la consulta y deberias de corroborar que no se perdiera ningun dato a mi parecer.

Answer (score 0):

Usando la libreria Sqlite-net-pcl tenes acceso al metodo `InsertAll` e inserta un conjunto de datos de forma rapida, muy superiormente a recorrer con un foreach e insertar un dato a la vez.

Te dejo un ejemplo de construccion de la base, creacion de tabla e insercion de datos.

```
    private void Base()
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection("cadenaConexion");

        db.CreateTable(typeof(Persona), CreateFlags.AutoIncPK);

        List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();

        db.InsertAll(personas);
    }
}
public class Persona
{
    string nombre { get; set; }
}
```